# How to stop parsing and reset yacc?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am writing a job control shell. I use Yacc and Lex for parsing. The top rule in my grammar is `pipeline_list`, which is a list of pipelines separated by a comma. Thus, examples of pipelinelists are as follows:

```
cmd1 | cmd2; cmd3; cmd4 | cmd5 <newline>
cmd1 <newline>
<nothing> <newline>
```

I represent a pipeline with the `pipeline` rule (showed below). within that rule, I do the following:

**1.** call `execute_pipeline()` to execute the pipeline. `execute_pipeline()` returns `-1` if anything went wrong in the execution of the pipeline.

**2.** Check the return value of `execute_pipeline()` and if it is `-1`, then STOP parsing the rest of the input, AND make sure YACC starts fresh when called again in the main function (shown below). The rationale for doing this is this:
Take, for example, the following pipelinelist: `cd ..; ls -al`. My intent here would be to move one directory up, and then list its content. However, if execution of the first pipeline (i.e., `"cd .."`) in the pipelinelist fails, then carrying on to execute the second pipeline (i.e. `" ls -al"`) would list of the contents of the current directory (not the parent), which is wrong! For this reason, when parsing a pipelinelist of length `n`, if executing of some pipeline `k > n` fails, then I want to discard the rest of the pipelinelist (i.e., pipelines `k+1..n`), AND make sure the next invocation of yyparse() starts brand new (i.e. recieve new input from `readline()` -- see code below).
if tried the following, but it does not work:

```
pipeline: 
simple_command_list redirection_list background pipeline_terminator // ignore these
{
if (execute_pipeline() == -1)
{
    // do some stuff
    // then call YYABORT, YYACCEPT, or YYERROR, but none of them works
}
}


int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        char *buffer = readline("> ");
        if (buffer)
        {
            struct yy_buffer_state *bp;
            bp = yy_scan_string(buffer);
            yy_switch_to_buffer(bp);

            yyparse()

            yy_delete_buffer(bp);

            free(buffer);
        } // end if

    } // end while
    return 0;
} // end main()
```

Comment: Suggestion: don't execute commands in the parser; build a tree and evaluate that in a separate  pass if there are no parser errors. You can handle errors without worrying about how that interacts with the state of the parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `YYABORT;` in an action to abort the current parse and immediately return from yyparse with a failure.  You can use `YYACCEPT;` to immediately return success from yyparse.

Both of these macros can only be used directly in an action in the grammar -- they can't be used in some other function called by the action.

Comment: I tried using YYABORT (as shown in the code section above), but it did not work.

Comment: Your code section above is syntactically incorrect and gives errors from bison.  Used correctly, YYABORT works fine.  Try creating an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the problems you are having.